# SignerSignEx as the Azure WebJob

Tags: c#, azure, sign, cryptoapi, webjob

I found a brilliant use of `SignerSignEx` on C# here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26372061

It works fine on the dev. machine, but on Azure WebJob you have to use something like this:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, 
                        certPassword, 
                        X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet |
                        X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet |
                        X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

But with `X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet` flag `SignerSignEx` returns hResult=-2146885626 (Error code 0x80092006 - No provider was specified for the store or object.)

How I can fix it and why MachineKeySet has influence on provider ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some research I almost sure (99% :) ) that `SignerSignEx` just doesn't work without user's profile. 
So I used mono + openssl.

Looks like a solution.

You can see an example of authenticode with Mono at:
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/security/signcode.cs

Bye,
have a beautiful time!