# How to programmatically sign an exe file with a certificate from a pfx file?

Tags: c++, windows, code-signing

I want to create C++ code (to run under Windows 10/11) that digitally signs an exe or dll file on my hard disk. The certificate is in a local pfx file with known password. Creating a process with signtool.exe would probably be the easiest but I'd prefer using some API function.

I found the example code at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/how-to-programmatically-sign-a-package. It needs a CERT_CONTEXT which contains the certificate. I found another example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/load-a-certificate-from-a-file which imports the certificate from a file. This sample calls the CertCreateCertificateContext function.

In my code, this function doesn't create a certificate, and GetLastError returns 0x80093102 (unexpected end of data).

This is the code in question with minimal error checking. I placed a comment on the line that retrieves the error code.

```
// Based on the code sample at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/load-a-certificate-from-a-file
HRESULT CreateContext(PCCERT_CONTEXT* cert)
{
    HRESULT  hr = S_OK;
    BYTE     certEncoded[20000] = { 0 };
    DWORD    certEncodedSize = 0L;
    HANDLE   certFileHandle = NULL;

    // open the certificate file from PFX_PATH
    certFileHandle = CreateFile(PFX_PATH, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == certFileHandle)
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // For simplicity, don't handle the case that the pfx file is longer than the buffer (in my test case, it fits into the buffer)
        BOOL result = ReadFile(certFileHandle, certEncoded, sizeof(certEncoded), &certEncodedSize, NULL);
        hr = result == 0 ? HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError()) : S_OK;
    }
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        // create a certificate from the contents of the buffer
        *cert = CertCreateCertificateContext(X509_ASN_ENCODING|PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, certEncoded, certEncodedSize);
        if (!(*cert)) {
            auto dwErr = GetLastError(); // 0x80093102 (unexpected end of data)
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwErr);
            CloseHandle(certFileHandle);
            hr = E_FAIL;
        }
        else {
            hr = S_OK;
        }
    }
    // close the certificate file
    if (NULL != certFileHandle) CloseHandle(certFileHandle);

    return hr;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Hans

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Programmatically Code-Sign an executable with a PFX (Bouncy Castle or Otherwise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26344271/how-to-programmatically-code-sign-an-executable-with-a-pfx-bouncy-castle-or-oth)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, thank you for pointing me to that article. After translating all the code from C# to C++, I got stuck with struct X509Certificate2 and interface ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm for which I cannot find a corresponding definition n C++.